# Is it possible to apply different filters to different charts in same Tableau worksheet?

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard

In the following image I have four charts with same measure. Currently all four are exactly same.

[image]

I want to add different country filters to these charts. For example, chart 1 should show view only for country 1, chart 2 for only for country 2 and so on. I have data only for 4 countries and current view shows data for all countries aggregated.

Is there any way to achieve this? I understand I can create separate worksheets for different countries and add into the dashboard. But I'm afraid it will mess up the viz. My dashboard is already filled with lot of stuff and I have to adjust this in bottom 20% of the dashboard.

Comment: did the answer solved your need? if so, please accept it in order to mark te thread as closed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 4 countries in your dataset (US, UK, China, India), and with "country filters" you just want to see that line chart for each one of them, just drag your country column in the rows shelf.

[image]

It seems to me that you may not need filters, just another dimension plotted into your worksheet, for the same metric.

Comment: Likewise, you can put Country on the Pages shelf instead of the Rows shelf to see "a page per country" instead of "a row per country".